# A man moves on a straight horizontal road with a block of mass 2 kg in his hand. He covers a distance 40m with an acceleration of 0.5m/s^2

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, work

We have to find the work done by the man on the block.

Can we consider the situation above as a non-inertial frame? The man is accelerating forward, therefore, a pseudo force will act on the box in the opposite direction which will be equal to

```
F = ma

= 2*0.5

= 1N
```

And since the force is in the opposite direction to that of the distance covered, the work done by the force will be negative i.e. -40J. Where is this approach lacking since the answer is not negative? The answer is 40J.

Comment: Please, focus your question to some physical concept (as opposed to an answer to a specific problem). Also, please use MathJaX for formatting .

Comment: IMHO, the task is ill-formulated. As @BioPhysicist says, man doesn't do any work on the block by itself, because in that frame block is stationary. But if you will analyze block with respect to the road, then yes- external force makes work of $40J$ on pushing "part of man-block system" for 40 meters, because you can split work by body parts.  But total work of this external force done is $(m_{man}+m_{block}) \cdot a \cdot \ell$.

Answer (score 1):

If you analyze this system from a frame moving with the man and block, then the work done is $0$ because the block is not moving in that frame. So, as you can see, the amount of work a force does depends on the reference frame; this is even true if you were comparing work done between two different inertial reference frames.

The problem probably wants you to analyze the system from a reference frame where the road is at rest.

Comment: If we analyze the system w.r.t the road, which is an inertial frame, the man is still accelerating. Therefore, the block is experiencing the pseudo force previously mentioned. I'm sorry if my interpretation of your response is wrong but can you please clarify what you just said above a bit? @BioPhysicist

Comment: The road is an inertial frame. The fact that the man accelerates does not change this.  There is no need for a pseudoforce in the road frame. What matters is the acceleration of the frame itself relative to another inertial frame and not the acceleartion of the objects described in the respective frame.

Comment: @Roli Pseudo-forces arise due to accelerating *reference frames*. Objects accelerating as view from inertial reference frames have no pseudo-forces acting on them. That is why they are called pseudo-forces; they arise due to the reference frame, and are not present in inertial reference frames.